# No consigo instalar cherrypy en android

Tags: android, python-3.x

En Android he instalado QPython3, exactamente la version 3.2 es la que me funciona.
Trato de instalar cherrypy desde el fuente y despues de instalar a mano las dependencias, resulta que desde el interprete de python al hacer import cherrypy, me devuelve el siguiente error....Class PerpetualTimer(threading.Timer): TypeError: function() argument 1 must be code, not str.

¿Alguna pista de por donde tirar?

Answer (score 0):

Este error se producía por que intentaba crear un clase a partir de una función. Resulta que threading.Timer era una función hasta la version  3.2 y pasó a ser una clase después. Luego el error se soluciona instalando la primera  version de  cherrypy que soportó 3.2 de python.